# SQL Server - How can I retrieve an ascending count-up of each value in a table, per row?

Tags: sql-server

Not exactly sure how i'd describe what I want, but I have a table with the following values:

```
ID GoodsNumber
1  700
2  701
3  700
4  700
5  701
```

How can I retrieve the ID numbers (and their associated GoodsNumbers), along with a count of the occurance of that GoodsNumber (Ordered by ID), so as follows:

```
ID GoodsNumber Count
1  700         1
2  701         1
3  700         2
4  700         3
5  701         2
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work - it just gives me a total count on each row:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.GoodsNum, B.Count
FROM Tbl A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT GoodsNum, count(GoodsNum) as Count
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY GoodsNum) B
ON A.GoodsNum = B.GoodsNum
```

Comment: Hope this helps  : SELECT *, Row_Number() over (Partition by GoodNumber ORDER BY Id) AS Count
FROM Goods
ORDER BY ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL 2008+ use `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT ID,
       GoodsNumber,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GoodsNumber 
                          ORDER BY id) [Count]
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY ID
```

to add a where add a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ID,
           GoodsNumber,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GoodsNumber 
                              ORDER BY id) [Count]
    FROM YourTable
    ) T
 WHERE ID = <yourVariable>
```

Comment: @MartinSmith Are you sure? I google row_number and say apply for 2008+  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Yes positive, that's either an error in BOL or they simply don't bother going back before that now.

Comment: Looks like they don't bother stating before 2008. I think you will accept that previous versions still had `SELECT`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx

Comment: Works great! although i've now realised i'd like to use a where clause to show data for a single ID. How would I do that yet still keep the count the same (so if I got ID 4, it would show a GoodsNumber of 700 and a count of 3)? Currently it shows a count of 1, cos im only retrieving a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`select
    ID
    ,GoodsNumber
    , row_number() over ( partition by Goodno order by id)  as [Count]
from  QC`